# Why can compactMap not remove nil values from an array of optional Any?

Tags: swift

I have this simple code, what I am trying to do is removing `nil` values from `[Any?]` and make an `[Any]`. But compactMap does not work!

```
let optionalString: String? = nil
let optionalInt: Int? = nil

let customTuple = (optionalString, "a", "b", "c", optionalInt)

let arrayOfChildren: [Mirror.Child] = Array(Mirror(reflecting: customTuple).children)

let arrayOfChildrenValues: Array<Any?> = arrayOfChildren.map({ element in element.value })

let compactArrayOfChildrenValues: Array<Any> = arrayOfChildrenValues.compactMap({ element in element })

print(compactArrayOfChildrenValues)
```

The printed result:

> [nil, "a", "b", "c", nil]

---

### Test:

For example, the following simple test would work! But my code in top does not! What I am missing here?

```
let optionalString: String? = nil
let optionalInt: Int? = nil
let array: [Any?] = [optionalString, "Hello, world!", optionalInt, 1000]
print(array.compactMap({ element in element }))
```

result:

> ["Hello, world!", 1000]

---

### Another Test:

```
let optionalString: String? = nil
let optionalInt: Int? = nil

let arrayOfChildrenValues: Array<Any?> = [optionalString, "a", "b", "c", optionalInt]
let compactArrayOfChildrenValues: Array<Any> = arrayOfChildrenValues.compactMap({ element in element })

print(compactArrayOfChildrenValues)
```

result:

> ["a", "b", "c"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change the type of `arrayOfChildrenValues` to `[Any]`, so it is no longer optional, since `\.value` doesn't return an optional.

Now - you want to see if the element of type `Any` is an optional. To do this, you can try match it to `Optional<Any>.none`.

Change the following parts:

```
let arrayOfChildrenValues: [Any] = arrayOfChildren.map(\.value)

let compactArrayOfChildrenValues: [Any] = arrayOfChildrenValues.filter { element in
    switch element {
    case Optional<Any>.none: return false
    default: return true
    }
}
```

#### Other ways

Here is another way:

```
let arrayOfChildrenValues: [Any] = arrayOfChildren.map(\.value)

let compactArrayOfChildrenValues: [Any] = (arrayOfChildrenValues as [Any?]).compactMap { $0 }
```

However, there is another method with some strange behaviour happening, I'm not sure I can fully understand.

Here's the code:

```
let arrayOfChildrenValues: [Any?] = arrayOfChildren.map(\.value)

let compactArrayOfChildrenValues: [Any] = arrayOfChildrenValues.compactMap { $0 }
```

The reason why this is strange is because all the other methods work with `arrayOfChildrenValues` being expressed like `{ element in element.value }`, however this *only* works when using key-paths. Perhaps it's because the return type is inferred as `[Any?]`, so it does a cast similar to the example above?

#### Why does your other example work?

The reason why `compactMap` doesn't work on `[Any]` is because a value of type `Any` cannot be *not* `nil`, since it is not an optional.

You can test this, by trying `compactMap` on `[Any]` instead of `[Any?]`. Modify your other example, as so:

```
let anyArray: [Any] = array.map { $0 as Any }
print(anyArray.compactMap({ element in element }))
```

Notice this prints `[nil, Optional("Hello, world!"), nil]` - and has also wrapped all our values in an optional because in reality this is still of type `[Any?]`, 'disguised' as `[Any]`.

Comment: Thanks, but my code should working, see my updated example, that works well. The issue of question is the same like in example. why it does not work there? And also I want use compactMap instead filter.

Comment: @swiftPunk Added a bit more detail at the bottom of my answer

Comment: I really cannot follow your answer and I do not understand it or may I am missing something, you said: `Any` cannot be `nil` ok! that is true but `Any?` can be `nil`, right? So because `Any?` can be `nil` then I am using `compactMap`

Comment: @swiftPunk Mentioning that made me think about it - yes you probably _should_ be able to cast to `Any?`. So I did a few tests, and the behaviour is slightly strange. Added info to answer about the results and other methods. I do find it strange the one which only works with key-paths though, I'm not sure how to explain that...

Comment: Yes you are right, I could use filter and solve the issue, but I noticed 2 deferent behaviour  of compactMap for same problem, firstly I dumped on my use case on all things, after double check I asked the question.

Comment: @swiftPunk Working with `Any` and `Any?` is weird :p Like how a value of type `Any` can actually have a type of `Any?`. Btw, my [ViewExtractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor) package I mentioned the other day makes use of checking if a type of `Any` is optional [here](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor/blob/09cc1e7bf7d1860b92b151bb0bf06ec25a9e9162/Sources/ViewExtractor/ViewExtractor.swift#L95), for example.

Comment: For me `Any` means: `String` or `Int`, `Bool`, `CGFloat` , ... and `Any?` means: `String?` or `Int?`, `Bool?`, `CGFloat?` , ... I see no issue in understanding of deference between `Any` or `Any?` PS: I believe the issue starts from tuple to having `nil` from beginning! I think that confuse Xcode badly! because we cannot have like this: `let test = (nil, 1, "Hello")`

Comment: @swiftPunk Writing `Any?` means you know there is definitely an optional, whereas `Any` can be anything, and may not be optional.

Comment: Try to give an optional value like `String?` or `Int?` to `Any`, Xcode would complain to you! if you fix it to `Any?`it does not complain.

Comment: @swiftPunk I can put `String?` into `Any`, what error is it giving you? Any type should be able to be represented by `Any`, including optionals

Comment: Here Warning: `Expression implicitly coerced from 'Int?' to 'Any'` and then `Force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning` and `Provide a default value to avoid this warning`

Comment: @swiftPunk An `as Any` after fixes that

Comment: As you said using `.map(\.value)` would solve the issue but having `.map({ $0.value })` or `.map({ element in element.value })` would not! why? is `.map(\.value)` more closer to cpu than the other two? what is happening? I would accept your answer, but I am letting the question be open to find the real reason. @George